# Convert.ToDecimal throws System.FormatExcept

Tags: c#, converters, formatexception

Im trying to parse from a xml file a value of say 2.25 to be a decimal separated by ",".

```
decimal hrsElapsed = Convert.ToDecimal(caseNode["hrsElapsed"].InnerText, new NumberFormatInfo() {NumberDecimalSeparator = ","})
```

However, I get a `System.FormatException` . The same line of code applyed to other fields does not throw it. For example here:

```
decimal hrsOrigEst = Convert.ToDecimal(caseNode["hrsOrigEst"].InnerText, new NumberFormatInfo() {NumberDecimalSeparator = ","});
```

I checked to see what the actual value of `caseNode[""].InnerText` which is "2.25" so I see no reason why I would get a Format Exception. Any ideas?

Comment: 2.25 uses dot as separator but in your NumberFormatInfo you have set coma as separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decimal has no implicit decimal separator, a string could have if you convert the decimal to one. So you need a `NumberFormatInfo`/`CultureInfo` that uses a dot as decimal separator to parse the string to `decimal`,f.e. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
decimal hrsElapsed = decimal.Parse(caseNode["hrsElapsed"].InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you need a `NumberFormatInfo`/`CultureInfo` that uses comma as decimal separator for `decimal.ToString`:

```
string hrsElapsedWithComma = hrsElapsed.ToString(new CultureInfo("de-DE")); // or another one that uses comma as decimal separator
```

Answer (score 0):

The NumberFormatInfo gives the converter hints on how to convert the string `caseNode["hrsElapsed"]` into a decimal. Because your string contains a "." and not a comma it's unable to parse it.

The data type `decimal` doesn't have a concept of digit decimal separator, only the string representation of it does.

Try removing the `NumberDecimalSeperator` and when you convert your decimal back to a string use it there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `decimal` type is a numeric type, it does not have any formatting itself. So there is no such thing as 'a decimal separated by ","' in C#. There are decimals, and there are strings which are created by formatting the decimal.

The format you are supplying to `Convert.ToDecimal` is the format that is used to convert the string to a decimal. Since the string you are converting uses a period, you should use that in your format.

To then convert that decimal number to a representation using a comma, convert it to a string using a suitable format.

```
        decimal hrsElapsed = Convert.ToDecimal("2.5", new NumberFormatInfo() {NumberDecimalSeparator = "."});
        string representationWithComma = hrsElapsed.ToString( new NumberFormatInfo() {NumberDecimalSeparator = ","});
```